# PHP 7: Fatal error: Class 'framework\core\base\Controller' not found

Tags: php, mvc, framework

Работаю над фреймворком и при использовании неймспейса, в output "красуется" ошибка:

> Fatal error: Class 'framework\core\base\Controller' not found in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\framework.loc\app\controllers\Posts.php on line
>   12

**Прилагаю код `framework/core/base/Controller.php`**

```
<?php

namespace framework\core\base;


abstract class Controller
{
    public $route = [];

    public function __construct($route)
    {
        $this->route = $route;
    }
}
```

**И код `app\controllers\Posts.php`**

```
<?php

use framework\core\base\Controller;

class Posts extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'Posts::indexAction()';
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        debug($this->route);
        echo 'testAction';
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема, ибо в проекте `Controller.php` существует, Namespace используется, полагаю, правильно.

UPD: Код autoloaders.php

```
<?php


define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('CORE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/framework/core');
define('APP', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app');

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $file = ROOT . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    $file = APP . "/controllers/$class.php";

    if (is_file($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

Comment: Кто подгружает классы? Автолоадер посмотреть бы

Comment: Добавил autoloaders.php

Comment: почему у класса Posts не прописан namespace?

Comment: 11-я строчка `autoloaders.php` только у меня вызывает подозрения?

Comment: Если удалить 11 строку, то в output выдаст error, мол "отсутствует контроллер Posts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = ROOT . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
$file = APP . "/controllers/$class.php";
```

Проблема скорее всего в этих строчках. Зачем вы два раза определяете `$file` ?
Сделайте `echo $file;` и посмотрите, соответствует ли полный путь файловой системе.

Советую вам для подключения библиотечных файлов использовать `composer`.

Comment: Комментирование первой строчки не помогает, дело не в ней, уж точно.

Comment: @4L3X попробуйте вторую закоментировать ;)

Comment: @4L3X, возможно у вас ни та, ни другая строка неверная. Обновил сообщение, перечитайте

Comment: Да-да, проблема в этом. Пытаюсь пофиксить. Вывод при echo $file - таков: C:/OpenServer/domains/framework.loc/app/controllers/framework\core\base\Controller.php

Answer (score 1):

Починил!

autoloaders.php

```
<?php

define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/framework/core/base/');
define('CORE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/framework/core/');
define('APP', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app');

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{

    $userFile = APP . '/controllers/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class . '.php');
    $coreFile = ROOT . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class . '.php');

    if (is_file($userFile)) {
        require_once $userFile;
    }

   if (is_file($coreFile)) {
        require_once $coreFile;
    }


    echo $coreFile;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $userFile;
});
```

Output теперь такой:

```
C:/OpenServer/domains/framework.loc/framework/core/base/Controller.php
C:/OpenServer/domains/framework.loc/app/controllers/framework/core/base/Controller.phpC:/OpenServer/domains/framework.loc/Posts.php
C:/OpenServer/domains/framework.loc/app/controllers/Posts.php
testAction
Array
(
    [controller] => Posts
    [action] => test
)
testAction
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

У Вас у Controller'а стоит неймспейс

```
namespace framework\core\base;
```

у класса Post, вы используете неймспейс

```
use framework\core\base\Controller;
```

В этом и ошибка, добавьте классу Post namespace

```
namespace framework\core\base\Controller
```

и используйте неймспейс контроллера который вы наследуете

```
use framework\core\base;
```

Comment: Я с вами не согласен. Ошибка не в этом

Comment: Ошибка не в этом, попробовал :(